# Systemd error after upgrading from 18.04 to 18.10

Tags: systemd, error-handling, glibc

After upgrading from 18.04 to 18.10 i got the following error:

*systemd[1]: segfault at ffffffffffffffc0 ip 00007fe716b80184 sp 00007ffcc7f9cf88 error 5 in libc-2.28.so[7fe716af5000+171000]*

I reboot my computer, restarted systemctl, resintalled systemctl, reinstalled libc6 and libc-bin and fixed broken packages but nothing of that solved the error. What else can i do?

I'm unable to use virtualbox and veracrypt.

Comment: Try launching VritualBox from a terminal window by typing in `virtualbox` and copy and paste the error into your [question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1085733/edit)  There might be a possibility that a folder somehow changed ownership from root:root to your username in the `/usr` folder like `/usr/lib` itself becoming owned by your username preventing virtualbox from running.

Comment: When I run VirtualBox it says that kernerl driver needs to  be reinstalled, but when I try to reinstall it, i get the error "org.freedesktop.systemd1 times out"

Answer (score 1):

Yep, it seems the issue in systemd or virtualbox, however i got reproduced it only with virtualbox-5.2.20.

I didn't face any problem with systemd by installing VB from Ubuntu cosmic repo:
`5.2.18_Ubuntu r123745`.

**P.S.** Solved on Ubuntu 18.10